# Understanding Android Application lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963426/binding-and-starting-a-service-when-application-starts/37963624#37963624) question before and the conclusion was that I needed more debug in order to understand the app's lifecycle. Here's the follow up, and I'm actually more confused.

My [Application.onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) method gets called twice: once when the app starts and once when I close it. Is this supposed to happen? The thing is, I have a service that I want to start when the app starts and stop when the app terminates. Apparently `onCreate` is called in both circumstances? Please advise.

Note: I'm currently not interested in background execution.

Edit: When closing the app, [Application.onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) is called *afer* the main activity's [Activity.onDestroy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()). I'm not sure how that could be relevant, and only adds to the confusion. The application is being "created" *after* its main activity is destroyed? Doesn't make sense.

Edit: Here to leave a sample log. The first time I ran the app and then closed it by tapping "Clear all". I believe that this would leave services running on the background. This log is for the second time I ran the app. Notice that `onCreate` is not called when the app starts and that it's called instead after I close it:

> 06-22 19:54:29.971 2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo I/PhoneWindow:
>   [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001 06-22
>   19:54:29.981 2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo D/PhoneWindowEx:
>   [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
>   06-22 19:54:29.981 2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo I/PhoneWindow:
>   [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000 06-22 19:54:30.001
>   2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo I/Activity: Activity.onPostResume()
>   called  06-22 19:54:30.011 2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo
>   I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true 06-22 19:54:30.011
>   2504-3647/com.demo.demochatdemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true 06-22 19:54:30.021
>   2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo D/Atlas: Validating map... 06-22
>   19:54:30.051 2504-3647/com.demo.demochatdemo I/Adreno-EGL:
>   : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Iac7c2e2837)
>                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
>                                                                        Build Date: 07/08/15 Wed
>                                                                        Local Branch: LA_BR_1_2_3_RB1_AU080_1285665
>                                                                        Remote Branch: 
>                                                                        Local Patches: 
>                                                                        Reconstruct Branch:  06-22 19:54:30.051
>   2504-3647/com.demo.demochatdemo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL,
>   version 1.4 06-22 19:54:30.061 2504-3647/com.demo.demochatdemo
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0 06-22 19:54:30.161
>   2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo V/ViewRootImpl: Contents drawing
>   finished : com.demo.demochatdemo/com.demo.demochatdemo.ContactActivity
>   06-22 19:54:30.171 2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
>   06-22 19:54:30.171 2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo I/Timeline:
>   Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@31f3e056
>   time:150361131

At this point I close the app and get the following:

> 06-22 19:54:40.621 2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo I/Activity:
>   Activity.onPostResume() called  06-22 19:54:40.641
>   2504-2504/com.demo.demochatdemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle
>   id: android.os.BinderProxy@31f3e056 time:150371603 06-22 19:54:46.861
>   4061-4061/com.demo.demochatdemo
>   I/com.demo.demochatdemo.ContactActivity: onCreate

`onCreate` is being called there.

Edit: here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo.demochatdemo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.demo.demochatdemo.ChatApplication">

        <activity
            android:name=".ContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ChatActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit: here's the code for the activity.

public class ContactActivity extends Activity implements Store.Delegate {

```
private static final String TAG = ContactActivity.class.getName();
private String displayName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView listView;

    final ChatApplication chatApplication = (ChatApplication)getApplication();
    final ContactActivity contactActivity = this;

    setContentView(R.layout.contact_view);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new ContactViewAdapter(this, chatApplication.getStores(), new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == motionEvent.getAction()) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ContactActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);

                TextView displayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
                CharSequence charSequence = displayName.getText();

                setDisplayName(charSequence.toString());

                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_STORE, charSequence);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }));
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps something else is creating a new instance of the application, I suggest you generate logs/trace with more information to confirm this

Comment: @meda updated, please revise!

Comment: @AndréFratelli Can you include your manifest file please?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri manifest added. I find all of this odd because the app is **really** simple.

Comment: This should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079232/oncreate-called-while-activity-is-stopped-but-not-destroyed-only-after-inst

Comment: @AustinHanson the code is in the linked question.

Comment: I don't see any activity code in your linked thread.

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot that discussion seems related to `Activity`, not `Application`. I considered using the same solution, but there's no `isTaskRoot` in `Application`.

Comment: @AustinHanson, again, this is **not** the Activity's `onCreate`, it's the `Application`'s !

Comment: @AndréFratelli Um... You're log only shows activity lifecycle events. There's in fact only one "onCreate" in your logs and it's tied to the ChatActivity. Posting your code lets us *find* the issue with the code rather than try to speculate based on your ruminations.

Comment: @AustinHanson added. Please let me know if you find something relevant.

Comment: @AustinHanson, and that log shows the activity because it's the active one. The log was on the `Application` instance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you stop the service before you close the app? The default implementation of Service.onStartCommand() returns START_STICKY. If you're not overriding it, I believe the service will be restarted which, implicitly, forces an Application instance to be started.

Comment: You might be right! I wasn't stopping the service because I hadn't implemented any mechanisms to track when the app closed. Now I use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and a flag to track whether any activity is enabled. I didn't run many tests yet, but haven't noticed this problem again yet. That makes perfect sense. I'll try overriding `onStartCommand` and let you know.